# Adding method to interface metaclass works only once

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

So adding a method to an interface metaClass adds it to every instance of interface implementations – but only once. Adding the method to every implementing classes works every time, for a change.

Cleaning the metaClass between reassigning the method does not seem to change anything.

Here is a runnable example:

```
interface X {}
class A implements X {}
class B implements X {}

X.metaClass.test = { println "v1" }
new A().test()
new B().test()

X.metaClass.test = { println "v2" }
new A().test()
new B().test()

A.metaClass.test = { println "v3" }
B.metaClass.test = { println "v3" }

new A().test()
new B().test()

A.metaClass.test = { println "v4" }
B.metaClass.test = { println "v4" }

new A().test()
new B().test()
```

and the result is:

```
v1
v1
v1
v1
v3
v3
v4
v4
```

Is this an intended behavior? If so, then why? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Are you expecting `v2`? In the interface, how may times same method can be declared? once right?

Comment: The output is expected; what is your expectation?

Comment: That's right, I'd expect that overriding the `test` method on the `X` interface would case invoking it to use the overridden behavior – i.e. printing the "v2" string.

I am sorry, but I do not really understand the obviousness in your rhetorical question. When I do sth like `metaclass.someMethod` I expect that I am not really declaring the same method twice, but overriding the previous declaration. Is there a way to do this some other way?

Comment: Also, if doing "metaClass.someMethod" was interpreted as "declaring the same method twice" instead of overriding the previous implementation (as it seems it _is_ interpreted when doing the same thing on the target class) I'd expect there was some kind of exception.

Answer (score 3):

Whoa, I think this may actually be a long-standing, unresolved bug ([GROOVY-3493](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3493)).  Looks like the issue is that once a method is declared in an interface, it cannot be overridden via the metaClass.  This restriction does not apply to classes.

So my guess is the first time you declare the method via the metaClass, it is properly initialized, since it did not previously exist.  But any subsequent updates to the interface metaClass method don't work because it's already present.  The class metaClass changes works since this bug doesn't apply to them.

The workaround listed in the ticket seems similar to the one you've found; namely, update the metaClass on both the interface AND the class(es):

```
​interface X {}
class A implements X {} 
class B implements X {}  

X.metaClass.test = { println "v1" } 

new A().test() 
new B().test()  

X.metaClass.test = { println "v2" } 
A.metaClass.test = { println "v2" }

new A().test() // Will print "v2"
new B().test()​ // Will print "v1" still
```

Comment: Woah, thanks for finding the bug, I looked for it as well but failed. Bugs in a long time language feature aren't something a sane developer ever expects so it's really good to know it is indeed the case and not my lack of understanding of how it was supposed to work.
And then... 8 years, nice! This one is even more seasoned than the #ProvidedGate https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784 and still not resolved!
I will leave the bounty for just a few more days so maybe it will gather some more attention.